# Redux connected component does not render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm new to redux, and currently trying to get a connected component to render, yet nothing renders. The header tag in Main.js should render, yet it doesn't. I really don't get what the problem is, there aren't any syntax errors, or compilation problems. Here's my code:

**App.js:**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Main from './Main';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        //state goes here
    }
}

// eg: const actionCreators = {...allStudentActions};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    // return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
    return;
}



const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

export default App;
```

**Main.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>PlaceMint</h1>
              {React.cloneElement({...this.props}.children, {...this.props})}
            </div>
          )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from  './components/App';


// import pages components



// router dependencies
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './store';





const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                    <Switch>
                        {/* All the pages go here, wrapperd in react router 'Route tags' see react router docs */}
                    </Switch>

                </Route>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
)

render(router, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem with your code is that you should place the `Route` inside of `Switch` component so it will only render one component for the matching route.

Probably your empty `Switch` is the problem as there is no matching component inside your route. Move the `Switch` or wrap your route inside it - depends on what you're trying to create.

Switch is used to only render the first matching route. For more details, please have a looke [here](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Switch).

You haven't posted your store definition so I've created a simple example store in the demo below or in the following [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-redux-example-with-react-router-jdqjk).

**Note:** The code below is just for reference. I couldn't get it to run here.

```js
/*
// import pages components
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
// router dependencies
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";

import React from "react";*/

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { greeting } = this.props;
    console.log(greeting);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>PlaceMint</h1>
        {greeting}
        {/*React.cloneElement({ ...this.props }.children, { ...this.props })*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    greeting: state.greeting
    //state goes here
  };
}

// eg: const actionCreators = {...allStudentActions};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  // return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
  return {
    dispatch
  };
}

const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

const initialState = {
  greeting: "hello from redux"
};

//import store from "./store";
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  return state;
};

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

const router = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        {/* All the pages go here, wrapperd in react router 'Route tags' see react router docs */}
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);

render(router, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.1/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/6.0.1/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but why did you comment out the React.cloneElement line in Main.js; from my understanding in the tutorial I was following, that allows all route children under App.js to access state, and props without having to use mapDispatch and mapState in every child element that needs access to the redux store.

Comment: I commented it because I got an error `React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed undefined.`. Can you share the link to the tutorial so I can have a look? Commented it to get a working example.

Comment: Oh the thing with the `Switch` is not right. It's OK like you have it. You could even remove it for testing. But then I don't see the problem in your code - maybe it's in your `store` file or the `React.cloneElement` thing.

Comment: Here's the link to the tutorial vid (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2IOqeubsBw&list=PLu8EoSxDXHP5uyzEWxdlr9WQTJJIzr6jy&index=10&ab_channel=WesBos) by WesBos; thanks so much.

Comment: I now see the point. Your switch is inside `Route` which is a problem. Place it below or around `Route`.

Comment: OK, not sure what this clone thing is doing. But if you'd like to debug the props I'd add `<pre>{JSON.stringify(this.props, null, 2)}</pre>` so it will pretty-print the props passed including the mapped state.

Comment: Thanks, that works, Main.js is rendered. But I still need that App.js route wrapping around the switch tag to (as stated in the video) "sprinkle" the store state, and actions on all child elements. Thanks anyway, I'll try figuring it out from here.

Comment: Good to hear that's working for you now. You don't need `Switch` for connecting to Redux it's something React-Router needs for routing. You need to have your routes inside `Provider` to be able to connect the components to your Redux store. Remove `Switch` testwise to see that it is not needed for `connect`.